# Инициализировать TabLayout c RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-tablayout

Встала задача. Суть в следующем, необходимо добавить поведение ViewPager для RecyclerView. Листание я могу реализовать при помощи снап хелпера

```
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Здесь никаких проблем, проблема в том, что на странице используются табы. У TabLayout есть замечательный метод setupWithViewPager(ViewPager). Так как такого нет для ресайклера, то пробуем его реализовать

```
public static void setupWithRecyclerView(TabLayout tabLayout, RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            if (layoutManager == null)
                return;

            try {
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
                int firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (tabLayout.getTabCount() > firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition) {
                    TabLayout.Tab tabAt = tabLayout.getTabAt(firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition);
                    if (tabAt != null)
                        tabAt.select();
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("TabLayoutUtils.setupWithRecyclerView(TabLayout, RecyclerView)" +
                        "could be called only with linear RecyclerView");
            }
        }
    };

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
//          recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(tab.getPosition());
//          recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

В итоге когда я листаю RecyclerView я получаю то, чего ожидаю - смену вкладок, нооо при клике на вкладку я попадаю в onScroll и так как вкладка на данный момент полностью видима, а onScroll вызывается постоянно, пока идёт скролл - смены вкладок не происходит (RecyclerView дергается, как и анимация выбора вкладок, но в итоге выбирается текущая вкладка). В onTabSelected можно увидеть закомменченные попытки отрубить и врубить onScrollListener, но это не помогает, так как анимация (скролл) обрубаетсся позже, чем заканчивается этот метод.

Кто то знает, как побороть подобное?

Answer (score 1):

решил просто, заменил

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(tab.getPosition());  
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
    }
```

на

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(tab.getPosition());
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> 
                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener), 50);
    }
```

а функцию селекта доработал

Было

```
        try {
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
            int firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (tabLayout.getTabCount() > firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition) {
                TabLayout.Tab tabAt = tabLayout.getTabAt(firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition);
                if (tabAt != null)
                    tabAt.select();
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("TabLayoutUtils.setupWithRecyclerView(TabLayout, RecyclerView)" +
                    "could be called only with linear RecyclerView");
        }
```

Стало

```
        try {
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
            int firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (mTabLayout.getTabCount() > firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition &&
                    firstVisibleItemPosition == lastVisibleItemPosition) {
                TabLayout.Tab tabAt = mTabLayout.getTabAt(firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition);
                if (tabAt != null)
                    tabAt.select();
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("TabLayoutUtils.setupWithRecyclerView(TabLayout, RecyclerView)" +
                    "could be called only with linear RecyclerView");
        }
```